# dados não são armazenado no Banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, post

Bom dia, fiz um editor de texto com php js e um pouco de jquery para o efeito slide do link. Porém ele não está armazenando no banco de dados e não me acusa nehum erro alguém pode me dizer como soluciono? desde já obrigado

```
<?php 

require "bd.php";

if (!empty($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['corpo'])) {
    $titulo = addslashes($_POST['titulo']);
    $post = htmlentities($_POST['corpo'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $data = date('d-m-Y');

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post (titulo, conteudo, data) VALUES 
    (:titulo, :conteudo, NOW())");
    $sql->bindValue(":titulo", $titulo);
    $sql->bindValue(":conteudo", $post);
    $sql->bindValue(":data", $data);
    $sql->execute();

    header ("location: dashboard.php");
    exit;
}else{
    echo "ainda não deu certo";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Post

```
    <div id="eda" >

        <div id="edmenu">
                <button id="b" onclick="bold()"><b>B</b></button>
                <button id="i" onclick="italic()"><i>I</i></button>
                <button id="u" onclick="under()"><u>U</u></button>
                <button id="link">Link</button><br>

                <ul id="fl">
                    <li><input type="text" name="linke" placeholder="coloque 
                a URL" id="vlink" value="http://www."></li>
                    <li id="ok" onclick="linkar()" ><button >Ok</button> 
                </li>

                </ul>
                <select id="fonts" onclick="fontFam();">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="Times New Roman">Times new Roman</option>
                    <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                    <option value="Consolas">Conolas</option>
                    <option value="Monospace">Monospace</option>
                    <option value="Sans-Serif">Sans-Serif</option>
                    <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
                </select>
                <select id="fontsize" onclick="fontTam();">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
                <label for="file-input" id="imagem">
                        <img src="imageicon.jpg"width="30" height="30" 
 name="imagem">
                </label>
            </div>
        <form method="POST" id="fte" name="fte">
        <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo" id="titulo"> 
 <br>
        <textarea id="corpo" name="corpo" style="display: none"></textarea>
        <iframe id="conteudo" name="conteudo" >
        </iframe><br>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" onclick="envie();">
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="editor.js"></script>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

O arquvo js

```
function iframe() {
conteudo.document.designMode = 'on';

}

function bold(){
conteudo.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}

function italic(){
conteudo.document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
}

function under(){
conteudo.document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
}

function fontTam(){
var se = document.getElementById('fontsize').value;

conteudo.document.execCommand('fontSize', false, se);

}

function fontFam(){
var fa = document.getElementById('fonts').value;

conteudo.document.execCommand('fontName', false, fa);

}

function linkar(){
var vl = document.getElementById('vlink').value;

conteudo.document.execCommand('createLink', false, vl);

}

function envie(){
document.getElementById("corpo").value = 
window.frames['conteudo'].document.body.innerHTML;
document.getElementById("fte").submit();
}
```

Comment: entra no if se os valores não estiverem vazios e executa o insert pelo menos deveria inserir, mas mesmo clicando no submit do formulario ele não armazena e não apareceu aquelas mensagens em laranja de erro

Comment: No SQL você define a coluna data como `NOW()` e em baixo tenta setar uma variável na `:data` porém ela não existe

Answer (score 0):

tenta esse codigo.
OBS: NÃO ESQUEÇA DE ABRIR A CONEXÃO COM A DB.

```
/* Prepare an insert statement */
$query = "INSERT INTO post (titulo, conteudo, data) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);

$val1 = '$titulo';
$val2 = '$post';
$val3 = '$data';

/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();
```